# Program returns an "IndexError: string index out of range."

Tags: python, string

```
from random import shuffle  

alphabet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"  

def substitution(alphabet,plaintext):  

    # Create array to use to randomise alphabet position  
    randarray=range(0,len(alphabet))  
    shuffle(randarray)  

    key="Zebra"  

    #Create our substitution dictionary  
    dic={}  
    for i in range(0,len(alphabet)):  
        key+=alphabet[randarray[i]]  
        dic[alphabet[i]]=alphabet[randarray[i]]  

    #Convert each letter of plaintext to the corrsponding  
    #encrypted letter in our dictionary creating the cryptext  
    ciphertext=""  
    for l in plaintext:  
        if l in dic:  
            l=dic[l]  
        ciphertext+=l  
    for i in alphabet:  
        print i,  
    print  
    for i in key:  
        print i,  
    print  
    return ciphertext,key  

# This function decodes the ciphertext using the key and creating  
# the reverse of the dictionary created in substitution to retrieve  
# the plaintext again  
def decode(alphabet,ciphertext,key):  

    dic={}  
    for i in range(0,len(key)):  
        dic[key[i]]=alphabet[i]  

    plaintext=""  
    for l in ciphertext:  
        if l in dic:  
            l=dic[l]  
        plaintext+=l  

    return plaintext  

# Example useage  
plaintext="the cat sat on the mat"  
ciphertext,key=substitution(alphabet,plaintext)  
print "Key: ", key  
print "Plaintext:", plaintext  
print "Cipertext:", ciphertext  
print "Decoded  :", decode(alphabet,ciphertext,key)
```

When I run this code, it returns a `"IndexError: String index out of range"` error. Could someone give me hand troubleshooting it, I can't see the problem.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File"/Users/Devlin/Desktop/Dev/Python/Substitution Cypher.py", line 57, in 
    print "Decoded :", decode(alphabet,ciphertext,key)
  File "/Users/Devlin/Desktop/Dev/Python/Substitution Cypher.py", line 41, in decode
    dic[key[i]]=alphabet[i] IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: Post the exact error message, including the line number and full traceback.

Comment: `code` Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Devlin/Desktop/Dev/Python/Substitution Cypher.py", line 57, in <module>
    print "Decoded  :", decode(alphabet,ciphertext,key)
  File "/Users/Devlin/Desktop/Dev/Python/Substitution Cypher.py", line 41, in decode
    dic[key[i]]=alphabet[i]
IndexError: string index out of range `code`

Comment: Also it's nice to highlight syntax, if you already have to use pastebin...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you need help with editing your question, such as formatting code, please see [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here:

```python
def decode(alphabet,ciphertext,key):  
    dic={}  
    for i in range(0,len(key)):  
        dic[key[i]]=alphabet[i] # this line fails
```

Your `key` at this point is always 31 characters, which is `len('Zebra') + len(alphabet)`. As `len(alphabet)` is always 26, `alphabet[i]` fails when i > 25.

I believe you've misunderstood what is represented by `key` here. `substitution` should *produce* a randomised key, it's not a password or a salt of any kind. In fact, if you look at [the original article you got this code from](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2009/12/python-cryptography-substitution-cipher-improving-on-the-caesar-cipher/), you'll see that `key=""` in `substitution` and not some-random-value.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0,len(key)):  
    dic[key[i]]=alphabet[i]
```

Here, `len(key) == len(alphabet) + 5`. Therefore, `i` (iterating over `range(0, len(key))`) goes further than is actual length of alphabet. This is due to part

```
key="Zebra"  #HERE, YOU START WITH ZEBRA

#Create our substitution dictionary  
dic={}  
for i in range(0,len(alphabet)):  
    key+=alphabet[randarray[i]]  #AND HERE, YOU ADD TO ZEBRA
    dic[alphabet[i]]=alphabet[randarray[i]]
```

So, again, you got more characters in `key` than in `alphabet`, and this results in the error.

The solution is to change line

```
key="Zebra"
```

to

```
key=""
```

Why did you want it to be "Zebra" anyway?

**P.S `range(x)` is the same as `range(0, x)`, so you should usually just write `range(len(key))` etc... **